# Regd. getting empty response with data mapper in wso2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to transform json to xml using datamapper and i am getting the empty xml structure but not getting any values in wso2. I have created data mapper dependencies and loaded both input and out structures and used AI to map json -> xml and they mapped correctly.

I tried on eclipse oxygen(esb-6.2.0) and integration studio(v8) also and deployed in EI(6.5.0) but still the behavior is same empty response structure. I kept a log in the in-sequence and it is logging the json request but not the xml response. I am not getting why the issue is happening.

Please provide your thoughts and attached the code to this post. Please do needful

Comment: will it be possible for you to attach the mediation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the API. In the API we need to specify the input and the output data type. In your case since the transformation is from JSON to XML, the input type needs to be JSON while the output type needs to be XML. But you have defined both as xml which resulted in this issue. Modify the input type to JSON and you will get the expected results

[image]

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DataMapper" context="/data">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/mapper">
      <inSequence>
         <log separator="/">
            <property name="payload" expression="json-eval($.body)"/>
         </log>
         <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/Wso2DataMapper.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/Wso2DataMapper_inputSchema.json" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/Wso2DataMapper_outputSchema.json" xsltStyleSheet="gov:datamapper/Wso2DataMapper_xsltStyleSheet.xml" inputType="JSON" outputType="XML"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

input

```
{
   "studNo":"Sample studNo",
   "studName":"Sample studName",
   "StudGroup":"Sample StudGroup",
   "studAddress":{
      "addrLine1":"Sample addrLine1",
      "AddrLine2":"Sample AddrLine2",
      "Mandal":"Sample Mandal",
      "District":"Sample District",
      "State":"Sample State",
      "Country":"Sample Country",
      "Zip":"Sample Zip"
   }
}
```

output

```
<Student xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <studentNo>Sample studNo</studentNo>
    <studentName>Sample studName</studentName>
    <studentGroup>Sample StudGroup</studentGroup>
    <studentAddress>
        <AddressLine1>Sample AddrLine2</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>Sample addrLine1</AddressLine2>
        <Mandal>Sample Mandal</Mandal>
        <District>Sample District</District>
        <State>Sample State</State>
        <Country>Sample Country</Country>
        <ZIP>Sample Zip</ZIP>
    </studentAddress>
</Student>
```